# MQTT protocol between RPi and sim808

Tags: mqtt

I have  an mqtt broker installed on RPi.
I want to send data meseaured from a sensor attached to Arduino to the broker in the RPi.
For this I am using a sim808.
I know that mqtt works in LAN how can I set a LAN between the RPi and the sim808

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Sim808 is a cellular GPRS data device (https://www.adafruit.com/product/2637), so getting data from it to a Raspberry Pi will depend on limits your wireless carrier has on the service that you have to sign up for. The data will have to travel from the Sim808, to the wireless carrier's data service that the Sim808 is connected to, out to the Internet, then to a publicly addressable node on your network (should be a Firewall) that is connected to the Internet, and then over to your Raspberry Pi MQTT broker.  This could be a very expensive way to get data to your MQTT broker, especially if both devices are relatively close. Have you thought about using WiFi? If your sensor is going to be sending data at a high rate, you could easily go over your wireless service's data plan, and end up with a very large bill at the end of the month :(

Comment: If I am using wifi then I should not use sim808 as it does not support wifi connection is that correct ?

Comment: Hi Abyr, I haven't seen a SIM808 that uses WiFi.  If all you are using it for is to get GPS info, there are much cheaper GPS sensors out there. Not sure where you are in the world, but here in the US, there are several sensor manufacturers for GPS that you could connect to something like an Arduino or ESP8266 board to send MQTT packets out over WiFi. (Adafruit would be one example: https://www.adafruit.com/product/746)